# "Utils.startApp()" not working in android version 10 & 11

Tags: react-native, react-native-native-module

I'm trying to start app from kill state. "Utils.startApp()" this method works perfectly fine in android version 7 or 8 but its not working in 10 & 11.
I think in android 10 or 11 needs permission but i don't know "What's the permission name".